# How to fix net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)?

Tags: json, fetch

```
fetch("./src/JSON/users.json",{
                method:'POST',
                headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Registraition_daten"))
            })
```

I woud like to send data to a json file, but i always get  net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed). What does it mean?